# Get swap used in last minutes

Tags: linux

I need to get the **one line output** of swap used in the last 10 or 15 minutes

I tried `vmstat`, `top` and `free` but all of these not giving result as per the above need.

Is there a command or script to do this?

Comment: It's not about programming, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to show the 1 line output of the current swap status. Calling multiple times at your chosen time intervals can give you the information you want, but depending on how the paged information is cached/removed, it may not give a 1-to-1 correspondence to bytes in/out. The command is:

```
$ swapon --show --noheadings --bytes
```

**Output**

```
/dev/sda1 partition 2153771008 4038656   -1
```

Which provides the `device`, `type`, `total swap`, `used`, `priority`.